# adding into an Array list of objects from a text file in java

Tags: java

i thinkj i have a type argument problem which im really confused about, Ive started with an Arraylist which, extends to the another class with my main methods. and i have a Events class, which i want to categorize from the txt file, the main problem i have is adding from my txt file which iread into an ArrayList, java pops up with this error message
incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to CSC8012.Events
But in my events it has String? Im really confused
This is my generic arraylist i think?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable> extends 
ArrayList<E> {

public void insert(E e) {
    this.add(e);
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for( lastIndex = this.size() -1 ; lastIndex > 0 && this.get(lastIndex-1).compareTo(e) > 0 ; lastIndex--){
        this.set(lastIndex, this.get(lastIndex-1));
    }
    this.set(lastIndex,e);
}
```

}

Heres my events class objects

```
public class Events implements Comparable<Events>{
//fields setting up the variables
String  ticketsbought;
String eventname;


public Events(String  ticketsbought, String eventname ){
    this.ticketsbought = ticketsbought;
    this.eventname = eventname;
}

@Override
public int compareTo (Events E){
    return
            ticketsbought.compareTo(E.getTicketsbought()) + eventname.compareTo(E.getEventname());
}

public String getTicketsbought() {
    return ticketsbought;
}

public String getEventname() {
    return eventname;
}

//setting it up for the main method from the constructor fields above



public void setTicketsbought(String  ticketsbought) {

    this.ticketsbought = ticketsbought;
}


public void setEventname(String eventname) {

    this.eventname = eventname;
}


@Override
public String toString()
{

    return "Tickets bought " + this.ticketsbought + "Event name " + this.eventname;
}
```

}

My main menu class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;
java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram extends SortedArrayList{

public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{



    boolean bye = false;
    String line;
    String option;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //tos take in our input
    do{




        System.out.println("Choose an option.."); // heres our options
        System.out.println("e Information on all events");
        System.out.println("c All information on clients");
        System.out.println("f to quit");
        System.out.println("b to update when tickets are bought by a registered Client");
        System.out.println("r to update the stored data when a Client cancels a ticket");
        option = sc.nextLine();

        switch (option) { // these are splitting our inputs to these cases with different outcomes
            case "e":
                //System.out.println("information on events");

                Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
                // Other declarations// Reading and processing the input data// Printing out the results outFile.close();
                ArrayList<Events> events = new ArrayList<>();


                while(inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                    String data = inFile.next();


                    events.add(data);//error based on these? Event is based off of arraylist<E> and inherits from those whilst i have them as string?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the exception because of [Generics in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Your ArrayList is declared to take Events objects.

```
ArrayList<Events> events = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, you are trying to add a String object to it.

```
String data = inFile.next();
events.add(data); //Cannot add a String object, only Events object allowed.
```

One way to fix this is to create an Events object using the String, and then add to the Arraylist. I am assuming each line has Event name and String in it, separated by a comma.

```
//Get your event name and tickets from the String data.
String tokens[] = data.split(",");
String eventName = tokens[0];
String ticketsBought = tokens[1];
//create an events object
Events eventObj = new Events(eventName, ticketsBought);
//Now add to your arraylist.
events.add(eventObj);
```

As an aside, you do not need to extend SortedArrayList in MainProgram. The main class is usually top level class in your project, and it will only contain objects (this is a common practice). If you want to use the new logic you have added in SortedArrayList, then instead of creating `ArrayList<Events> events = new ArrayList<>();`, you can create `SortedArrayList<Events> events = new SortedArrayList<>();`